# How to relevel factor in Rbased on another table

Tags: r, dplyr, factors

I'm trying to use `forcats::fct_relevel()` to relevel factors in mydf to match the order of the factor in lookup:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

mydf <- data.frame(id=1:10, f=as.factor(c("feb", "mar","mar","mar","jan","jan", "apr", "apr","mar", "jan")))

lookup <- data.frame(f=as.factor(c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr"))) #the order i want

levels(mydf$f) #defaults to alphabetical

mydf %>% group_by(f) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = n()) #want this in the order of lookup$f

mydf %>% 
  mutate(f = fct_relevel(f, levels(mydf$f))) %>% #the problem line
  group_by(f) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = n())
```

I understand that I can manually define the levels within `fct_relevel()`, but I can't afford to hard code it every time. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just do `levels(mydf$f) <- lookup$f` first?

Comment: Ok so `mydf %>%  mutate(f = factor(f, levels=lookup$f)) %>%  group_by(f) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = n())` works for sure. Is there a `forcats` equivalent?

Comment: ok fair enough thanks.

Comment: Maybe `lvls_reorder`, though it is a bit convoluted - `mydf %>% mutate(f = lvls_reorder(f, match(lookup$f, levels(f)))) %>% group_by(f) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = n())`

Comment: I'm happy to accept either if you want post a formal answer.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination would be to just fix it before doing any analysis:

```
levels(mydf$f) <- lookup$f
```

...which you could embed in your piped call like:

```
mydf %>% mutate(f = factor(f, levels=lookup$f)) %>% group_by(f) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = n())
```

Otherwise you could use `lvls_reorder` in a bit of a clunky fashion:

```
mydf %>% 
  mutate(f = lvls_reorder(f, match(lookup$f, levels(f)))) %>%
  group_by(f) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = n())
```